# How to send value from dropdown menu of bootstrap to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have create searching bar with filter button that can search between Teacher and Student name. First i can search to my database with fix to student but when i try to use filter button nothing send value from dropdown button So this is my poor code please come and help me

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
            <button name="filter" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="dropdownMenu1">
                <span class="selection pull-left">Select an option</span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="box-shadow:0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176)">
                <li><a href="#Teacher" class="" data-value="Teacher"><span>Teacher</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#Student" class="" data-value="Student"><span>Student</span></a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#all">All</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">          -->
        <input name="txtSearch" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" placeholder="Search term..."
            value="<?php echo $wordSearch; ?>">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
    var selText = $(this).children("span").html();

   $(this).parent('li').siblings().removeClass('active');
      $('#vl').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
    $(this).parents('.input-group-btn').find('.selection').html(selText);
    $(this).parents('li').addClass("active");
  });

</script>
```

I have no idea about PHP 
PS. Everything are under the same page (pls see attached picture below)
http://upic.me/i/hg/ssssss.jpg

Answer (score 1):

A link is not a form element. You need to tell a form field (which will send the value - compared to a link) about the value.
You are actually already doing this in your javascript with this line:

```
$('#vl').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
```

Now you just need to create the corresponding form field (with attribute id="vl") in your form.
In this example use the "hidden" form field like this.
Just add this somewhere between the   tags:

```
<input type="hidden" id="vl" name="vl" value="">
```

And then you can get the value in PHP with:

```
$_POST['vl']
```

Comment: Ok, First you are understand what's the purpose of my issue, So i write this code to test and nothing came out
`<input type="hidden" id="vl" name="vl" value="">
        <?php 
              $filter = null;
              if(isset($_POST['vl']))
              {
                $filter = $_POST['vl'];
              }
            echo $filter;     
          ?>`
one more question Have i need to click submit button to send value or just click list on dropdown menu then value will send ?
Because i test this 
`<input type="text" id="vl" />`
and it's work instantly when i selected from dropdown menu

Comment: Right now it won't submit just by clicking, but you could add `$("form").submit();` after `$(this).parents('li').addClass("active");` to make it submit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at posting data to the backend for a search you either need a ajax post to do it asyc (something like jquery ajax method) [docs here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

if you are wanting to use a form you'll need to read up on html forms [heres the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms) before you get started on the php side of things